# Identification of Non-Gaussian State Space Model

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, state-space-models, identifiability

The following paper details necessary assumptions in order to have a non-gaussian state-space model be identifiable (see A1-A5); '[A General Linear Non-Gaussian State-Space Model: Identifiability, Identification, and Applications](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v20/zhang11/zhang11.pdf)'

Using Stan, I've attempted to implement a state-space model according to these five assumptions, but my model remains unidentifiable. I suspect that I'm not understanding A2 in the paper, and would like to see where my misunderstanding lies;

A2 states:

"$F$ is of full column rank, and $G$ is of full rank."

In my particular case, my model is of the form;
$$ y_t=Fx_t + \epsilon_o $$
$$ x_t=Gx_{t-1} + \epsilon_s $$

and both $F$ and $G$ are square matrices, and $G$ is a diagonal matrix, so that it is by necessity a full rank matrix.
Now for $F$, I am under the impression that no constraint needs to be placed on it's structure. For example, if I have a $5\times5$ matrix $F$, it could be full (all elements may be estimated from the observables, $y_t$) and would still yield an identifiable model, provided it is full column rank. To be explicitly clear, we could have;

$$ F = \begin{bmatrix}
    f_{1,1} & f_{1,2} & f_{1,3} & f_{1,4} & f_{1,5} \\ 
    f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & f_{2,3} & f_{2,4} & f_{2,5} \\
    f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3} & f_{3,4} & f_{3,5} \\ 
    f_{4,1} & f_{4,2} & f_{4,3} & f_{4,4} & f_{4,5} \\
    f_{5,1} & f_{5,2} & f_{5,3} & f_{5,4} & f_{5,5}
  \end{bmatrix} $$

However, I'm beginning to suspect a stronger constraint must be placed on $F$, something like:

$$ F = \begin{bmatrix}
    f_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    f_{2,1} & f_{2,2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    f_{3,1} & f_{3,2} & f_{3,3} & 0 & 0 \\ 
    f_{4,1} & f_{4,2} & f_{4,3} & f_{4,4} & 0 \\
    f_{5,1} & f_{5,2} & f_{5,3} & f_{5,4} & f_{5,5}
  \end{bmatrix} $$
Which is clearly full column rank, but also rather restrictive (which I don't enjoy).

So; I would appreciate it if someone could point out any errors in my thought process. I would be happy to answer questions about my model as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Assume $\epsilon_0 = 0$, you know $x$, and you know $y$.  Would you be able to deduce $F$ in the first case?

Comment: No, I don't see a way in which I could do that--I would have a system of 5 equations but 25 unknowns. Sorry, I don't think I follow your thought exercise here.

Comment: Hi again--I don't think I thought hard enough when I made my last comment. I do believe it's possible to recover $F$ from known $y_t, x_t$, provided the length of the series $y_t$ and $x_t$ are long enough.

Comment: In the first case, you only have five unknowns, so, since $x_t$ and $y_t$ both have to have length five for the matrix dimensions to work out, you can recover $F$ from a single observation.

Comment: I appreciate your time, and I'm sorry if I'm being a bit dim here, but I don't see how there's five unknowns in the first case. I'm treating each of the elements in the matrix $F$ as unknown, so that the first matrix has 25 unknowns.

Comment: Your question was, essentially, do we need a stronger constraint on $F$ than full column rank?  Since your first example is clearly identifiable, despite having a row rank equal to one, that should tend to push your thinking towards "no".   The conditions are on $F$, not on what you assume to be true about $F$.

Comment: Ah, I see your reasoning now--Thank you for being so patient with me there. As it turns out, the issue I was experiencing was due to numerical stability/overflow. Sorry for taking up your time.